# Should I pass an app-wide object into objects that need it, or should I use a singleton?

Tags: c#, ios, oop, xamarin.ios, singleton

In my specific situation, I am passing a "facebook" object (i.e. an instance of MonoTouch.FacebookConnect.Facebook) down through nested view controllers, and it is adding a decent bit of code to the project. There is always exactly one instance of the object after it is instantiated in the AppDelegate, and it is used in most of the view controllers in the app. All of the view controllers that utilize the facebook object have something like this at the beginning:

```
public class MyViewController : UIViewController
{
    Facebook facebook;

    public MyViewController (Facebook facebook)
    {
        this.facebook = facebook;
    }
    // ...
}
```

...except the top-level view controller, where the object is instantiated.

There is also a scenario where it is passed "through" a nested view controller, just for the sake of getting it to a more deeply nested view controller that utilizes it.

I know that singletons are generally frowned upon and go against OOP principles. I want the code to be easily maintainable. Am I taking the right approach or would a singleton do the trick without compromising code quality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would avoid the Singleton at all costs.  Your approach encourages loose-coupling and allows you to increase your testability by mocking out the object (if you converted it from your concrete implementation).  It generally adds more code but you should have better testability in your application.  That allows you to use an IoC container and utilize Dependency Injection.  There are many great articles and posts on the web and here on StackOverflow about such topics.

Perhaps your singleton might look like this:

```
public class MyViewController : UIViewController
{
    public MyViewController ()
    {
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        FaceBookSingleton.Instance.DoSomeAction();
        FaceBookSingleton.Instance.Something = 4;
    }
}
```

How do you do your testing around `Foo()`?  How would you know, sooner, if you introduced a breaking change?  How do you know what your dependency graph looks like?  It's harder to test code like this.  Don't count on people browsing your code base to try and figure out if they broke something.  Help them out and yourself out by writing code that can be tested.

Now maybe look at something as such:

```
public interface ISocialMediaWidget
{
    ISocialMediaWidgetResponse DoSomeUnitOfWork();
}


public class ConcreteSocialMediaWidgetService
{
    protected readonly ISocialMediaWidget socialMediaWidget;

    public ConcreteSocialMediaWidgetService(ISocialMediaWidget widget)
    {
        this.socialMediaWidget = widget;
    }

    public ISocialMediaWidgetResponse Foo()
    {
        return socialMediaWidget.DoUnitOfWork();
    }
}
```

Writing tests around the aforementioned is much easier.  You can also mock out the response from each interface to create all kinds of tests.

```
public void SocialMediaWidgetTest()
{   //pseudo code
    var testService = new MockObject(ConcreteSocialMediaWidgetService(MockObject_of_ISocialMediaWidget));
    Assert.Equals(someImplementation_of_ISocialMediaWidgetResponse, testService.Foo());
}
```

Comment: Good point. I haven't implemented unit testing with this project yet, but I plan to do so in the future. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again for the other example.

Comment: More code means more tests.  It also makes refactoring that much harder, which is a blow to long-term stability of the code base.  It's a myth that Singletons are not testable.  The more-testable code you provided would work just as well inside of the singleton holding on to the Facebook instance - testing pre and post code could easily reset the singleton instance as required.

Comment: @KendallHelmstetterGelner: I didn't say they weren't testable.  I said they are *harder to test*.  The code was just a snippet.  It's harder to test as a Singleton because you can't guarantee that the call to Facebook.Instance.Foo() didn't have an unintended consequence in the call to DoSomeAction().

Comment: DoSomeAction() is no different than your DoUnitOfWork() call.  So basically the code with a singleton looks like:  FaceBookSingleton.Instance.DoUnitOfWork().  It's just as mockable.  Meanwhile using that approach he's avoided a ton of code that will get in the way if he needs to change code around, or support more than one social media service.  If he stays the course, all of the VC code has to know what a ISocialMediaWidget/Facebook object is, increasing coupling.  Just all around it's creating way more problems than it solves.

Comment: @KendallHelmstetterGelner I'm glad to see not everyone is deathly afraid of singletons ...

Comment: @KendallHelmstetterGelner: Using an IOC container you can reconfigure the implentations of the interface so you don't have to have it as tightly coupled.

Comment: With the power of correction that CLANG offers in terms of static analysis, I don't see why anyone would move to an approach (IOC) that CLANG could not help verify.  CLANG is basically acting like a system that is doing simple unit testing for you, so if you are all for unit testing you should not take approaches that weaken the testing the system does for you automatically.  This is in a thread about Mono though, perhaps CLANG does not apply with Monotouch?

Comment: Also I simply do not see how any approach that requires you to pass an object through parts of the system that do not need it, can ever have looser coupling than a system that can access rarely used parts directly.  Coupling to me is both static and dynamic ties between parts of the system.  Passing around some generic blob may help intermediaries not have to include interface specifics, but it still means they have to keep track of, and forward on this object they have been passed.  If you purposefully wanted to create spaghetti code I could think of no better approach.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, singletons are largely just an alternative syntax for other perfectly acceptable OO strategies, like "factories" and memoization.

It's a question of syntax and what each syntax implies in your organization. If you do this, is it implied in your organization that some work might be done to product `MyClass.Current`?

```
public class MyClass
{
  public static MyClass Current
  {
    get
    {
      if (SomeSortOfCache['MyClass.Current'] == null) {
        // do something to get populate it.
      }
      return SomeSortOfCache['MyClass.Current'];
    }
  }
}
```

Or, would your organization prefer something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public static MyClass GetCurrent()
  {
    if (SomeSortOfCache['MyClass.Current'] == null) {
      // do something to get populate it.
    }
    return SomeSortOfCache['MyClass.Current'];
  }
}
```

Or, if you want to think of it as a factory, call the method `BuildMyClass()` or `CreateMyClass()`. Under the hood, the mechanisms are largely the same. It primarily a question of assumptions your organization makes about each syntax + naming convention.

Secondly, you've established that you only want or need to allow one instance of  to exist. So, I'd suggest using a pattern that facilitates this gracefully, with the least amount of code.

Comment: My organization is a small startup, and we don't have a preferred approach. I mainly want to know if using a singleton approach would compromise code maintainability down the road.

Comment: @JonathanNesbitt I haven't come across any issues in my applications. And on the contrary, I've actually run into *many* issues sorting out endless "parameter chains" and redundant data-fetches that creep up when singletons and/or factory-type patterns are religiously avoided. Whatever you do, do it purposefully and establish an understanding amongst your team as to what each pattern implies. In other words, when I hit ApplicationUser.Current or HttpContext.Current, I can expect they behave similarly under the hood. Neither one writes to my database, etc. ...

Comment: I work for a small startup, and I am the sole iOS developer. I don't have the time right now to implement unit testing - my main goal is to get v1.0 to the App Store quickly. I was hoping to save a little time by not having to copy/paste the repetitive code. I don't want to make the code untestable for the future, though.

Comment: @JonathanNesbitt For my own education, what's exactly is the testing concern?

Comment: I plan to add unit tests to the project in the future so that I can find breaking changes quicker, and hopefully make the project more stable as other developers are introduced.

Comment: @JonathanNesbitt Singletons bind classes and methods to contexts. But, this doesn't inhibit a singleton-dependent method from using a parametized version under the hood or providing an override. E.g., I *normally* want to know whether `protectedObject.hasAccess()` as it pertains to `ApplicationUser.Current`. And, I don't want every page or sleepy dev to replicate code to find the current user. So, the lazy code reduces bugs and increases readability. And, in rare, necessary cases (testing for instance), I can still easily provide an alternate user, `protectedObject.hasAccess(user)`.

Comment: @jonathanNesbitt You have time to do unit testing. You spend some time writing unit tests; you save time finding problems easily that you otherwise find the hard way. Xcode makes it _really_ easy to add unit tests.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, a singleton would seem to be a better solution as you would eliminate a lot of repetitive code, and increase flexibility for changes as you quickly build out your application.

A singleton could also act as an intermediary to the Facebook object, making it simpler for various parts of your application to use.

Any resource that is limited in nature is a good candidate for accessing through a singleton.

Comment: I like the idea of eliminating repetitive code (which is really why I asked in the first place), but svidgen made a really good point about keeping the code testable. I plan on implementing unit tests in the future, so I will keep the approach I am using. Thanks!

Comment: You can easily mock out a singleton as well, remember (as another reply said) that really a singleton is a kind of factory - one where you can easily swap out the singleton instance method when operating a test harness.  iOS as a system makes good use of singletons (like UIApplication, or UIDevice) so use of singletons is a natural fit with the system as a whole.

Comment: @KendallHelmstetterGelner Thanks for this: "a singleton is a kind of factory"

Answer (score 0):

I can prefer to use singleton approach as you need always only one instance.